# LDAP query for returning members of specific groups

Tags: ldap, design-patterns, group-membership

I need to get some users from LDAP, only those that belong to groups whose names begin with a pattern, something like this

```
((&objectcategory=user)(memberof=cn=**groupNamePattern_***,OU=distribution,DC=xx,DC=com))
```

I think it needs to do some sort of sub-query, so that it first retrieves the list of groups that match the pattern, then the users of those groups.

How such query can be expressed?

Answer (score 0):

Why not query for:
`(cn=**groupNamePattern_***)`

with a base of OU=distribution,DC=xx,DC=com

and return the member list.

Comment: I retrieve the list of groups with (&(objectcategory=group)(name=pattern*))   how can those queries be merged into a single one?

Comment: @azathoth: So in your query for the group, return the member attribute.  That will return all groups that match the pattern, and their member list.  So loop through the list of returned values.

Comment: Can you provide a sample query, please? I'm new to LDAP

Comment: Use the one you have, for (&(objectcategory=group)(name=pattern*)) and in your list of retrieved attributes list off member.  Then you have a list of groups, (The ones you want) and their members.  Which combined is the list you seem to want.

Comment: I have done some research, and found out that I can't use wildcards in LDAP filters for attributes containing LDAP distinguished names, as my requirement states (I need to get the users in a single query, no scripts involved). Thank you, anyway

Comment: @azathoth Were you able to find the solution for this? I'm trying to get all users from a group starting with a pattern. It works only when I specify the full name in the user filter condition. Let me know if you have the solution for this. Thanks in advance.